# app.config not getting transformed after installation of nuget package

Tags: c#, nuget, app-config, nuget-package, xdt-transform

Please find attached **app.config** and **app.config.install.xdt** file content. Not able to find the cause of not transofming the file. The goal is to remove the added plugin under  tag in app.config once my custom specflow package installation is complete. 
Is there any tool available where we can see the log(s) while install the nuget package and show wheather config file transformation is successful or fail? 
I already searched for other questions but no clue. Both the xml files are valid as I validat them from https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/.

**app.config content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    <section name="specFlow" type="TechTalk.SpecFlow.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionHandler, TechTalk.SpecFlow"/>
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %P{Level}%4P{Source} - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="[%-5level] %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>

  <specFlow>
    <!-- For additional details on SpecFlow configuration options see http://go.specflow.org/doc-config -->
    <plugins>
      <add name="Com.Plugin.Gherkin.SpecFlow.2.4" path="Com.Plugin.Gherkin.SpecFlow.2.4" type="Generator"/>
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

**app.config.install.xdt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <specFlow>
    <plugins>
        <add xdt:Transform="Remove" />
    </plugins>
  </specFlow>
</configuration>
```

**Package.nuspec**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Sushil</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>stade</authors>
    <owners>stade</owners>
    <licenseUrl>http://LICENSE_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>http://PROJECT_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>http://ICON_URL_HERE_OR_DELETE_THIS_LINE</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="SampleDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <!--Add Section to Uninstall and Re-install Application.Config files-->
    <file src="app.config.install.xdt" target="content" />
    <file src="app.config.uninstall.xdt" target="content" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Comment: Show your NuSpec. How do you include the XDT?

Comment: @CodeCaster Please find Package.nuspec in edited question section.

Comment: You're missing the file name, `target="content\app.config.install.xdt"`

Comment: @CodeCaster but without providing the content\app.config.install.xdt. I am able to see the content folder created and both the files are available inside. Now I modfiy the nuspec but still app.config is not getting trasformed.